# Sorting JSONObject using a value of a JSONArray in Java

Tags: java, json, json-simple

I have following JSONObject i am trying to sort:

```
{
  "coords": {
    "27": {
      "x": [70,71,72],
      "y": [1945,1946,1947],
      "lineNumber": [
        19
      ]
    },
    "29": {
      "x": [70,71,72],
      "y": [1945,1946,1947],
      "lineNumber": [
        91
      ]
    },
    "2333": {
      "x": [70,71,72],
      "y": [1945,1946,1947],
      "lineNumber": [
        10
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I wanted to sort the JSONObjects inside `coords` w.r.t the value `lineNumber`. `lineNumber` array always has only one element inside. I am using simple JSON.

Comment: Do all `lineNumber`s contain a single element? If so why are they defined as arrays?

Comment: @JanezKuhar I thought the same thing but the implementation of web service is done by someone else. Which i can't change that's why i am having a bit trouble as i am also new to Java as well.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there isn't a clean way to do this.

You can convert your map to a list of [`Map.Entry<K,V>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) objects. In your case the entries are of type `Map.Entry<String, JSONObject>` (entries inside `coords`).

The list can then be sorted by entry `V`alues, or in your case `JSONObject`s. The easiest way to do this is to write a custom [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and sort your list via [Collections.sort(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)).